# Can use BULB mode from Camera Remote API

Tags: android, camera, sony

I am working on a simple mobile app that controls the camera from phone. I am interested to take pictures with custom shutter speed. UP to 30 second exposures are easily controlled by setting the shutter speed via API, however longer exposures require use of BULB mode.

Is there way take a picture with BULB mode from the Camera Remote API?

This seems to be a blocker for some use cases i.e. extended bracketing and some weird forms of time-lapse that I want to shoot.

PS I am struggling with few more topics - setting metering mode (spot, center, multi), setting white balance tint (green - purple axis as opposed to temperature yellow - blue). Is there way to control these parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 4 of the Camera Remote Application now supports a lot of new functions. Some of those include:

1. Bulb
2. Continuous
3. RAW, movie file download and deleting contents from the SD card

It seems metering mode and the actual metering result is still unavailable. The white balance still only exposes temperature (yellow/blue) and no tint(green/magenta).

These are described in the camera remote API SDK v.2.20 https://developer.sony.com/downloads/all/sony-camera-remote-api-beta-sdk/

Thank you Sony folks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, none of those are supported in the API currently.

White balance is supported in the current API for QX series and Alpha cameras like A7, NEX-5000, RX100 MIII, however I don't believe tint axis is controllable.